Interface names changed on 22.04 HWE kernel upgrade from 6.5 to 6.8
The built in interface names on a server with an integrated X-722 controller with 4 ports changed after upgrading from 22.04 HWE kernel 6.5 to 6.8. I thought Predictable Network Interface Names would guarantee the same names across kernel upgrades. The following shows the interface names before and after the kernel upgrade:
eno1 ---> eno1np3
en02 ---> eno2np2
en03 ---> eno3np1
en04 ---> eno4np0

In 6.5, lshw short for these interfaces looks like this:
/0/0/0/3/0       eno4             network        Ethernet Connection X722 for 10GbE SFP+
/0/0/0/3/0.1     eno3             network        Ethernet Connection X722 for 10GbE SFP+
/0/0/0/3/0.2     eno2             network        Ethernet Connection X722 for 10GbE SFP+
/0/0/0/3/0.3     eno1             network        Ethernet Connection X722 for 10GbE SFP+

Is this a bug? Will this be corrected? This is for many servers so the configuration is a pain to fix.
Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Ubuntu Servers by default use the GA kernel stack so there is no change; the HWE kernel stack is default for Desktop & later flavor installs; you mention Server (no release) and HWE which is not a standard/default kernel stack.

@guiverc thanks for the comment. We are running 22.04. The HWE kernel may not be a default, but that does not mean it is not allowed or unsupported on servers. We needed a bug fix that was not back ported to 5.15. Regardless, the 6.8 kernel is standard for 24.04 and it should not be changing interface names. These interface names are the same on 5.15 and 6.5.

Yes the HWE kernel stack is supported in jammy or 22.04, but as its not default for Servers, there isn't the same mention of your issue until you read the notes written for those upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04.1  (in the release notes) which is where Server users are expected to use the 6.8 kernel (by default), otherwise just standard documentation (https://documentation.ubuntu.com/server/explanation/networking/configuring-networks/ etc)

You may want to look into some of the answers here for renaming your devices.

There's also a similar answer to a similar question which came about when interface names were originally changed from eth0.
